# Key lemma in the proof of Levy's Continuity Theorem

Tags: probability-theory

I am trying to understand the following lemma in the proof of Levy's Continuity Theorem:

> Let $\mu_{n}$ be a probability measure. Then,
>   \begin{equation}
> \mu_{n}\Bigg(x: |x| \geq \frac{2}{T}\Bigg) \leq \frac{1}{T} \int_{-T}^{T}(1-\phi_{n}(t))dt.
> \end{equation}

Now by the Fourier Inversion Theorem, we have that,

\begin{equation}
\lim_{T \longrightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-T}^{T}\frac{e^{-ita}-e^{-itb}}{it}\phi(t)dt = \mu_{n}(a,b) + \frac{\mu_{n}\{a,b\}}{2}.
\end{equation}
Taking $a = - 1/\varepsilon$ and $b, T = 1/\varepsilon$, we have,

\begin{equation}
\lim_{\varepsilon \longrightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-1/\varepsilon}^{1/\varepsilon}\frac{e^{it/\varepsilon}-e^{-it/\varepsilon}}{it}\phi(t)_{n}dt = \mu_{n}(-1/\varepsilon,1/\varepsilon) + \frac{\mu_{n}\{-1/\varepsilon,1/\varepsilon\}}{2},
\end{equation}
implying, 
\begin{equation}
1-\lim_{\varepsilon \longrightarrow 0} \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-1/\varepsilon}^{1/\varepsilon}\frac{e^{it/\varepsilon}-e^{-it/\varepsilon}}{it}\phi_{n}(t)dt \sim \mu_{n}[-1/\varepsilon,1/\varepsilon]^{c},
\end{equation}
indeed impying heuristically that the behavior of the tail of the distribution is determined by the behavior of $\phi_{n}(t)$ around $0$. However, in the above heuristically derived formula, we have that we're analyzing the inverse Fourier Transform of $\phi_{n}(t)$. However, the lemma stated above has no complex exponential multiplying $\phi(t)$, and my understanding is that the inverse Fourier Transform fo $\phi_{n}(t)$ reveals information about $\mu_{n}$. I seem to follow the details of the aforementioned lemma, but I can't quite see through the details.

It'd be great if someone could help me out.

Comment: The inequality is known as "truncation inequality", you can find a proof for instance in the book by Dudley ("Real Analysis and Probability") or by Ushakov ("Selected topics on characteristic functions").

Comment: @saz Yes, I was able to go through the proof on my mine. I still don't understand why we don't have $e^{-itx}\phi(t)$ in the integrand, because the inverse Fourier Transform is the function that yields information about the distribution. I suppose I followed with the heuristic computation I did above, and argued that if the complex exponential were there, the $sin$ term would drop out. The integral of the $cos$ would be of of the form $sin(f(\varepsilon))/f(\varepsilon)$, and in the limit when $\varepsilon$ is very small, this term is arbitrarily small so it's as if we can ignored it.

Comment: Does this heuristic argument make sense? I was trying to motivation the the consideration of the expression on the RHS on my own. After this has been done, one can start off from the RHS and integrate and see what pops out to give us a quantitatively correct inequality.

Comment: Note that $$(e^{it/\epsilon}-e^{-it/\epsilon})/(it) = 2 \sin(t/\epsilon)/t$$ i.e. to get your heuristic motivation you have to study the behaviour of this term in dependence of $t$. For small $t$ the term is close to $2$ and for large $t$ it is very small (because of the boundedness of $t$).

Comment: @saz, yes, that's pretty much what I argued. Well, I argued it the other way, by varying $\varepsilon$, and not $t$, because $\varepsilon$ controls the bounds with respect to which I'm interested in measuring the tail the distribution. To go further out, $\varepsilon$ has to be made small, and the function $sin(t/\varepsilon)t/\varepsilon$ decays when $\varepsilon$ is made large.

Comment: Does that makes sense?